# Python 2.7 crashes in pymol application

Tags: 14.04, crash, python-2.7, pymol

I am new to ubuntu, please forgive me for any logical comments.

While attempting to load a [pdb file](http://www-jmg.ch.cam.ac.uk/data/molecules/misc/methane.pdb) in pymol, I will get a system crash report:

```
ProblemType: Crash
Architecture: amd64
CrashCounter: 1
CurrentDesktop: Unity
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 14.04
ExecutablePath: /usr/bin/python2.7
ExecutableTimestamp: 1434999065
ProcCmdline: python2.7 -m pymol.__init__
ProcCwd: /home/administrator
ProcEnviron:
 LANGUAGE=en_SG:en
 TERM=xterm
 PATH=(custom, no user)
 XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=<set>
 LANG=en_SG.UTF-8
 SHELL=/bin/bash
```

I have tried a few methods e.g. installing nvidia drivers; upgrading to the latest kernel; reinstalling python2.7 and pymol.
But i can't seem to fix this issue.

These are my systems information:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

$ uname -r
3.13.0-86-generic


$ lsmod | grep nouv
nouveau              1097288  3 
mxm_wmi                13021  1 nouveau
wmi                    19177  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  19476  1 nouveau
ttm                    93424  1 nouveau
drm_kms_helper         55071  1 nouveau
drm                   303102  5 ttm,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 nouveau

$ dpkg -la | grep python2.7
libpython2.7:amd64                                    2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2                                    amd64        Shared Python runtime library (version 2.7)
libpython2.7-minimal:amd64                            2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2                                    amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 2.7)
libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64                             2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2                                    amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (standard library, version 2.7)
python2.7                                             2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2                                    amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 2.7)
python2.7-minimal                                     2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2                                    amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 2.7)
pymol                                                 1.7.0.0-1                                           amd64        Molecular Graphics System
```

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Pymol starts to work fine without python crash after i revert the nvidia driver back to an older version 304.131.
Installed through Ubuntu repository:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

You can also specific a version to install, e.g.
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

Hope these helps.